# VBA Excel Use integer variable from another module

Tags: excel, vba, integer

I have

```
Dim PackageInnerHorizontalwidth As Single
```

In "Public Sub PackageDimensionsCalculator()" which is a result of some calculations. Now I need to use that resulting value "PackageInnerHorizontalwidth" in Module "Function EvaluateFormatSketch() As Boolean" And it returns that value as "0" which is not the actual resulting value after all teh calculations. I tried to make that first

```
Dim PackageInnerHorizontalwidth As Single
```

Global and public but with no success. I understand that it's not the way to do that in my case.

So my question is: How to get "PackageInnerHorizontalwidth" as value in module "Function EvaluateFormatSketch() As Boolean"?

Right now I have it as

```
Dim PackageInnerHorizontalwidth As Integer
```

Would someone , please, help me on this one?

Comment: Might help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables

Comment: Change the `Sub` into a `Function` and return the value.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^ This should really be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Global and public but with no success. I understand that it's not the
> way to do that in my case.

But it is. Put:

```
Public PackageInnerHorizontalwidth As Single
```

in the top of the module (outside/before your function) and remove any dimming of it in the functions.

Comment: I can't do that because it's a result of calculations prior in the sub. It returns "Invalid attribute in sub or function" error. And If I place that before  "Function EvaluateFormatSketch() As Boolean" returns it as "0" which is not it's actual value.

Comment: @Eduards - skip the public variables and [use a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871910/vba-excel-use-integer-variable-from-another-module#comment118207793_66871910).

Answer (score 5):

Used inside a procedure scope, the `Dim` keyword declares a *local variable*.

Inside a procedure scope, you can only declare *local* variables; local variables live & die within the scope they're declared in.

If you need to access a variable from more than one single scope, you have several options:

- Promote the local variable to *global scope* by moving its declaration into a module's *declarations section*, changing the keyword to `Public`: the variable is now accessible from all procedure scopes *in all modules*. That's usually a rather bad idea.
- Promote the local variable to *module level* (move its declaration into the module's *declarations section*), either keeping the `Dim` keyword or changing it to `Private`: the variable is now accessible from all procedure scopes *in that module*. Likely also a bad idea.

Note that `Public` and `Private` keywords (and the deprecated `Global` keyword too) are illegal in local scope.

There are other options, but before we look into them let's re-look at this statement:

> In "Public Sub PackageDimensionsCalculator()" *which is a result of some calculations.*

A `Sub` procedure does not have a "result". `Sub` procedures *do something*, they don't *return* any results. We can *make* it actually return a result two ways:

- `ByRef` return: we could declare a `ByRef` parameter, and use it to "return" the result:

  ```vb
  Public Sub PackageDimensionsCalculator(ByRef outResult As Single)
      '...do the calculations...
      outResult = ... ' <~ assign the return value before procedure exits!
  End Sub
  ```
- Change it to a `Function`. `Function` procedures have one purpose: take inputs, compute a result, *and return it*:

  ```vb
  Public Function PackageDimensionsCalculator() As Single
      '...do the calculations...
      PackageDimensionsCalculator = ... ' <~ assign the return value before procedure exits!
  End Sub
  ```

Now `EvaluateFormatSketch()` can get the value by invoking the function:

```vb
Public Function EvaluateFormatSketch() As Boolean
    Dim pckgDimensions As Single
    pckgDimensions = PackageDimensionsCalculator

    'return a Boolean value by assigning to the function identifier:
    EvaluateFormatSketch = pckgDimensions > 0
End Function
```

Or with a `ByRef` return:

```vb
Public Function EvaluateFormatSketch() As Boolean
    Dim pckgDimensions As Single
    PackageDimensionsCalculator outResult:=pckgDimensions

    'return a Boolean value by assigning to the function identifier:
    EvaluateFormatSketch = pckgDimensions > 0
End Function
```

Consider renaming `PackageDimensionsCalculator` so that its name begins with a verb, e.g. `CalculatePackageDimensions`, noting that it's suspicious to have a procedure that calculates something *but doesn't take any inputs*. Consider refactoring any inputs as parameters, making the caller responsible for getting the values that affect the calculation - the function will be much easier to test/validate (and eventually, to maintain/debug) if all its inputs & dependencies are passed as parameters.

Comment: "That's usually a rather bad idea." - needs bolded, underlined, highlighted, whatever emphasis can be added hahah.