# Stop processing when there was an error in the previous of consecutively called subs

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have three subs that runs one after another, the subs are called `DataTrimming`, `Pivot` and `Email`.

```vb
Sub AllTogether()
    DataTrimming
    Pivot
    Email
End Sub
```

I put an error handler inside `Sub DataTrimming`, so when there is an error, there will be an error message and exit the sub.

When I run `sub AllTogether`, it shows the error message when there is an error from `Sub DataTrimming` and it continues to run `sub Pivot` and `sub Email`.

Is there a way to exit `sub AllTogether` and not run the rest of the subs  when an error occurs in `sub DataTrimming`?

Comment: I can see two solutions. 1st, put an error handler in AllTogether and propagate the error from DataTrimming. 2nd, use a "status" return values and check it to see if procedure must be continued

Answer (score 3):

Use an `On Error` statement to handle runtime errors and redirect execution to a line label:

```
Sub AllTogether()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    DataTrimming
    Pivot
    Email

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    'break here and debug if needed; use Resume without a label to get back to the failing call.
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

If any of the called procedures have their own respective error-handling subroutines, then you'll want to re-throw the error in that procedure in order to have it handled in the scope of the `AllTogether` procedure, using `Err.Raise` like so:

```vb
Sub DataTrimming()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    '...do stuff...
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    '...handle errors locally
    Err.Raise Err.Number 'rethrows the same error with the same message
End Sub
```

---

Side note, the procedures have a *temporal coupling* issue because they are clearly side-effecting procedures that *must* be invoked in a particular specific order. To fix this, you would turn `DataTrimming` into a `Function` procedure that *returns* the data that the `Pivot` procedure needs to intake as parameters; similarly, making `Pivot` a function that returns data that the `Email` procedure needs as parameters, would remove the coupling and reduce (or remove!) reliance on global state - in the end it might look something like this:

```
Dim trimmedData As Object
Set trimmedData = DataTrimming

Dim pivotedData As Object
Set pivotedData = Pivot(trimmedData)

Email pivotedData
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872549/1188513) for various ways of passing data around procedures without involving globals.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning if any of the inner subs has an error handler, the outer will not break but will keep going. In that case the error will have to be re-thrown once handled.

Comment: I like the addition. Also, it is worth mentioning that the error handler in the calling procedure will 'handle' possible errors in `Pivot` and `Email`, so it won't be possible to know which one errored. I would appreciate it if you could comment on my solution since it has kind of a smell (`Sub` written as a `Function`). Is there a possible improvement?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to change your three subs DataTrimming, Pivot and
Email to Functions instead, each of which returns a Boolean.  Return True from each unless they hit an error, in which case return False.

In Altogether(), check the value that comes back from DataTrimming before continuing to Pivot (if False, Exit Sub) and the same for continuing from Pivot to Email.

Answer (score 1):

### Error Handling Among Procedures

- You could rewrite your `DataTrimming` procedure as a function returning a boolean (e.g. `True` if successful) and use the boolean in the calling procedure (give it a better name though).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AllTogether()
    
    If wasDataTrimmingSuccessful Then
        Pivot
        Email
    End If
    
End Sub


Function wasDataTrimmingSuccessful() As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    
    ' DataTrimming code in here
    
    
    wasDataTrimmingSuccessful = True
    
ProcExit:
    
    Exit Function

clearError:
    'Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Function
```

Comment: This works, of course. I would however advise against turning `Sub` procedures into `Boolean`-returning functions to indicate success or failure, because 1) it hides the actual error, 2) a side-effecting procedure should either succeed or throw, and 3) it changes the paradigm of failure and forces the caller to check the return value. On the other hand, naming the `Boolean`-returning function e.g. `TryTrimData` or `WasXxxxSuccessful` like you did, makes it obvious at the call site that it's actually a function we're calling and that the return value needs to be checked, so probably fine :)

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that refactoring to fix the *temporal coupling* in the OP's code becomes much more complicated; if `DataTrimming` were a function that returned the trimmed data, then `Pivot` could take the trimmed data as a parameter and return whatever the `Email` procedure needs to intake as a parameter, then the procedures have clear inputs & outputs and a clear logical ordering, and no chance of ever modifying the code and end up with the procedures invoked in the wrong order. If they're already `Boolean` functions returning error state, it's much harder.

Comment: Pure gold. Thanks a lot. Will have to avoid it like the plague.