# vba error handling from one procedure for all functions

Tags: vba, ierrorhandler

My question is here about possibility of another(short) way solution;

In vba I have a procedure, which call numerous functions, and in that functions some of them also other functions. I need a universal error handler, which exits sub and writes err.Description to screen.

I know how to write it on each function.

```
On Error GoTo errorhand
'block of code
Exit Sub(function)
errorhand:
MsgBox Err.Description
Exit Sub
End Sub(function)
```

Is there any way, other than to write these piece of code on each function?
(Due to each error opens in specific function, I donot think writing this code to main procedure will lead to error handler to show up in every function where error happens)

Comment: If each function needs to do different things on error, then yes, each function must have its own error handling. Otherwise, the calling main method should have one, and the functions none. The error in a function will propagate to the method which called it.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905735/stop-processing-when-there-was-an-error-in-the-previous-of-consecutively-called/66906060

Comment: Giving error handling on single Call, does not help me. That's why I put on every function same Exit Function errors on multiple criterias. Thanks for links